# Difference between ClientScope and ClientClaims in Identity Server 4

Tags: entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I am trying to setup a configuration interface for our Identity Server 4 implementation with a custom database using Entity Framework Core. During client configuration, there's a `Claims` property of type `ClientClaims`, and also an `AllowedScopes` property of type `ClientScopes`. What is the difference between client claims and client scopes?

Comment: Since this got answered on github - maybe you should provide the answer here for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

"Think of client claims as static claims associated with a client - mostly useful for server to server style scenarios." -leastprivilege commented on Jan 10 on Github

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/674